# how to find max value from multiple columns MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, max

[image: could`t create table here so had to printscreen]

So the question is how can i show the Supplier (S) that has the maximum quantity (QTY) from table SP.

This is what i came up with:

```
  SELECT sno FROM sp WHERE sno in (SELECT max(QTY) FROM sp WHERE qty);
```

but it is showing only empty field, and i cannot find the problem.
I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM tableA a
     INNER JOIN tableB b
        ON a.S = b.S
WHERE b.qty = (SELECT max(qty) FROM tableB)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c175/1)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*with ties*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23b99/1)

Answer (score 1):

how about

`SELECT sno FROM sp ORDER BY qty DESC LIMIT 1`

that way you can index on QTY and not have to do a full table scan

And you can then use joins to get to your data in S without having to do subselects or anything costly like that

`SELECT s.* FROM sp LEFT JOIN s USING(sno) ORDER BY qty DESC LIMIT 1`